# Hello , could somebody help me with Matrice notation in equation begining?

Tags: equations, matrices

Need to get code for this, I don't get how to write (N x 1) under:

[image: matrix]

Answer (score 3):

That's a job for `amsmath`'s `\underset`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\underset{(N \times 1)}{\mathbf{R}_t}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]